# Creating or modifying event without firing calendar trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a trigger on calendar modification. In this one I would like to be able to modify an event whose time has just been changed by the user (by delivering the correct time which is stored in a Google Sheets).

Or recreate the event if it was accidentally deleted by the user.

Is this possible without triggering the same calendar trigger ?

Comment: There's only one [Google Calendar Event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_calendar_events). What's your goal for having different calendar triggers?

Comment: in fact the question is rather to know if the calendar trigger is triggered when I create, modify or delete events inside the script that has been runned by the trigger himself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calendar trigger won't be triggered if you modify the calendar (create, update, delete events) inside the trigger itself, but as a workaround, you could call that same function inside itself. For example:

```
// Global variables
var counter = 0;

// Calendar Trigger
function onCalendarTrigger(e) {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('your-calendar-id');
  // Create a random event
  calendar.createEvent(`Test Created ${Math.random()}`,
    new Date('May 15, 2020 20:00:00 UTC'),
    new Date('May 16, 2020 21:00:00 UTC'));
  if(counter < 1){
    // Increment the counter 
    // before the onCalendarTrigger function is being called again
    // In this way, you will not enter in this section again 
    counter++;
    onCalendarTrigger(e);
  }
}
```

Be careful with this workaround, because if you do it wrongly, you'll enter in an infinite loop and you'll surely hit the [Apps Script Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).